# Extracting specific string in a line with sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

In a line of string like this:

```
"<testcase_name> +config=<main_cfg> +cfg1=<cfg1> +cfg2=<cfg2> +testlength=<string> +print_cfg=<string> +print_match=<string> +quit_count=<string>"
```

I would like to extract those strings that are after `+cfg1=` and `+cfg2=` only, and not including these specific configurations: `+config=`, `+testlength=`, `+print_match=`, `+print_cfg=`, and `+quit_count=`.

So I would like to store the result in a variable and be able to view it as:

```
echo "other_cfg = $other_cfg"
% other_cfg = cfg1.cfg2
```

Notice a `.` separates `cfg1` and `cfg2` strings. Is there a single line (if possible in sed) that can do this?

More conditions:

1. `+cfg1` and `+cfg2` could be any string AND there could be more of them. So the key here is to just not include these known configs: `testlength`, `config`, `print_match`, `print_cfg`, and `quit_count`.
2. The configs are not always in that order as the example above, except for `+config=` which is always the first one.
3. Any of the known configs mentioned in (1) may not be present in the line.

Examples:

Input 1:

`testA +config=reg +input=walk1s +print_match=1 +testlength=short`

Expected output 1:

`% other_cfg = walk1s`

Input 2:

`testA +config=mem +quit_count=50 +order=reverse +input=rand +testlength=long`

Expected output 2:

`% other_cfg = reverse.rand`

Comment: Use can use this as regex `(?<=\+cfg[12]=<)(.*?)(?=>)`. https://regex101.com/r/tM1aK4/1

Comment: Put some effort into your sample input and expected output. For example, you say the fields can be in any order so show AT LEAST 2 lines of sample input/ouput. We don't know if you want the fields output in the order they appeared in the input or some other order. You want a shell variable populated with the result - one for all lines of input or one per line of input or something else.There's a LOT you haven't told us about your requirements for multi-line, multi-position input.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish throwing out some "regexp" that some online tool thinks is valid is useless. Every tool supports different flavors of regexp so to provide a useful solution you need to identify which tool you have in mind and which options you need it to use. That regexp would not work, for example, in any standard UNIX tool - e.g. sed, awk, or grep (non-GNU without -P). You also missed the point that the OP doesn't want to find a string matching a regexp, he wants to find the strings that do not match a list of other strings.

Comment: @renvill so are you telling us that your input file will always contain exactly 1 line? If not then instead of showing us a bunch of individual lines, just show us one multi-line sample input file and the associated output, multi-line or otherwise.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, sorry if the requirements come in pieces. This is actually inside a shell script already. So the input is really just a single line. Specifically, this line of code is where I wanted to do the config  extraction:            other_cfg=`echo $tc | sed -e 's/.*\+config=[a-z0-9_]*//' | sed -e 's/\+testlength=[a-z0-9_]*//' | sed -e 's/\+print.*=[a-z0-9_]*//' | sed -e 's/ \+.*=//' | sed -e 's/ //'``  (shell scripting beginner here, sorry ^^)

Comment: There's an excellent chance you've completely misunderstood the purpose of shell scripting. The UNIX shell is an environment from which to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and to call tools for everything else with a language to sequence those calls. It is NOT a language for manipulating text, that's what `awk` is for - shell just calls it. So if you've written a shell script that's manipulating text and calling sed or awk etc. in some parts of the script then you are doing it wrong. In particular any time you write a shell loop to manipulate text you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, thank you very much for your input. I may have presented the script is doing simple text manipulation and that's all. What it does is actually wrapping a very complicated one (which I didn't want to touch as it's a common file in our workarea), manipulating its outputs (which the 'config extraction' problem is one of them), monitoring processes for proper job termination, and many more. Not a single shell loop to read lines in a file and manipulate text inside can be found in my script. Please understand my background is not in hardcore scripting, sed, awk, perl, unix, etc.

Comment: Understood, but I assume you want to learn how to to do it the right/easy/concise/efficient/robust/maintainable way instead of some other way. Anyway I've provided a solution that is the right way to do what you want, feel free to ask questions if you have any,

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. That's not what this problem is so it's not a job for sed, it's a job for awk.

```
$ cat file
"<testcase_name> +config=<main_cfg> +cfg1=<cfg1> +cfg2=<cfg2> +testlength=<string> +print_cfg=<string> +print_match=<string> +quit_count=<string>"
testA +config=reg +input=walk1s +print_match=1 +testlength=short
testA +config=mem +quit_count=50 +order=reverse +input=rand +testlength=long

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    FS="[ =]+"
    split("config testlength print_match print_cfg quit_count",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        skip_cfgs["+"tmp[i]]
    }
}
{
    other_cfg = ""
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        if ( !($i in skip_cfgs) ) {
            other_cfg = (other_cfg=="" ? "" : other_cfg ".") $(i+1)
        }
    }
    print "% other_cfg =", other_cfg
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
% other_cfg = <cfg1>.<cfg2>
% other_cfg = walk1s
% other_cfg = reverse.rand
```

Comment: The "that is all" part of "sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all." is simply not true, though of course some people may only want to use it for simple substitutions on individual lines.  The "s" in "sed" is for stream, not line; e.g. the N command enables multi-line editing. The ability to write functions within sed illustrates it's not just for "simple" substitutions.  sed is however lightweight :-)

Comment: @peak no, it is true. I use sed daily and have done for 30+ years but the N command and every other sed command except s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. People just use all that other stuff today for the mental exercise, an awk script will always be better in almost every way (e.g. clarity, efficiency, maintainability, robustness, portability, and often brevity).

Answer (score 0):

If `+cfg1` and `+cfg2` are guaranteed to always been in that order in the line, then yes; just subst out everything else:

```
sed 's/.*+cfg1=<//;s/>.*+cfg2=<//;s/>.*//'
```

Otherwise, you'll want at least `awk`.

Comment: The comment that "Otherwise, you'll need at least awk" is strictly speaking incorrect (sed is Turing-complete), and indeed handling the possibility that the keys could be in either order is not so difficult to do in sed (e.g. if the OP requirements allow it, the string could be normalized fist).    See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed on Turing-completeness.    Of course, there are often good reasons to use awk in preference to sed.

Comment: Point taken. I will change "need" to "want".

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^\S+\s+(.*)$/other_cfg = \1\n+config=+testlength=+print_match=+print_cfg=+quit_count=/;:a;s/ (\+\S+=)\S+(.*\n.*)\1/\2/;ta;s/ \+[^=]*=/./g;s/\./ /;P;d' file
```

This replaces the first string by the required one and adds a lookup table to the pattern space which includes all the config strings not needed. The unwanted config strings are then iteratively removed and remaining configs morphed into the required output.

Comment: I can't imagine how that script can tell where to separate the "words" from `config...count` so I tried it with input `"<testcase_name> +config=<main_cfg> +print=<cfg1> +cfg2=<cfg2> +testlength=<string> +print_cfg=<string> +print_match=<string> +quit_count=<string>"` (i.e. `+print=<cfg1>` instead of `+cfg1=<cfg1>`) and it output `other_cfg = <cfg2>.<string>` instead of `other_cfg = <cfg1>.<cfg2>`. I won't pretend to know why it did THAT specifically!

Comment: @EdMorton quite right, I over simplified the lookup table. Specific configuration strings are now as is.